# How to print enum constants

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum class that I cannot modify.  I want to print

JENNIFER
MICHAEL
WILLIAM

In the Main class that is accessing this Enum class I keep getting this output:

Jenny
Mike
Will

What code can I write in my Main class to get the output I want?

```java
public enum NickNames

{
    JENNIFER("Jenny"),
    MICHAEL("Mike"),
    WILLIAM("Will");

private final String name;

NickNames(String s) {
    this.name = s;
  }

public String toString() {
      return this.name;
  }

public static String[] getNickNames() {
      String[] output = new String[(values()).length];
      int i = 0; byte b; int j; NickNames[] arrayOfNickNames;
      
      for (j = (arrayOfNickNames = values()).length, b = 0; b < j; ) {
         NickNames h = arrayOfNickNames[b];
        output[i++] = h.toString(); b++; 
      }
      
      return output;
  }
}
```

Here's an example of code that is getting the wrong output.

```
NickNames[] nn = NickNames.values();
System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(nn));
```

Comment: It's because of your `toString()` method. If you need that override to be there, you need to explicitly call the `name()` method on each enum to get the literal name of each value. You can also create a `getName()` getter for your custom attribute, and call that where you're currently calling `toString()`. That will remove the default printing of name attributes where `toString` is being called implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

For a quick simple workaround, see the correct [Answer by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274572/642706).

Or, revamp your enum class to define a `getDisplayName` method rather than overriding `toString`.

## `toString` is not for user-interface

Your Question is a good example of abusing the override of [`Object#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method.

The `toString` method is designed for use in debugging and logging. Generally *not* intended for use in the user-interface.

For enums, I would generally advise not overriding `toString`.

### `getDisplayName`

Instead, **add another method to the enum** class for the purpose of accessing a name meant for display in the user-interface.

Commonly, such a method is called `getDisplayName`. For example, [`Month#getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) and [`DayOfWeek#getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)).

By the way, an enum should generally be named in the singular.

Tip: Name your parameters descriptively. IDEs commonly display the parameter name in the code editor as a prompt. So `NickName( final String displayName )` rather than `NickName( final String s )`.

Here is some untested example code.

```java
public enum NickName

{
    JENNIFER( "Jenny" ) ,
    MICHAEL( "Mike" ) ,
    WILLIAM( "Will" ) ;

    // Member fields.
    private final String displayName;

    // Constructors.
    NickName( final String displayName ) {
        // Verify argument.
        Objects.requireNonNull( displayName ) ;  
        if( displayName.isBlank() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException() ; }
        // Remember argument.
        this.name = displayName ;
    }

    // Accessors.
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName ;
    }
}
```

By the way, your `getNickNames` method is probably not necessary. In modern Java, the calling programmer could just as well write something like this untested code:

```
String[] nickNames = Arrays.stream( NickName.values() ).map( NickName :: getDisplayName ).toArray() ;
```

If you believe that to be too much for your particular calling programmers, I suggest changing your implementation of `getNickNames` to be that one-liner. I found that method’s code in your Question to be difficult to read and comprehend.

And change the name of that method to `getDisplayNames` for consistency and clarity.

```java
    public static String[] getDisplayNames() {
        return
                Arrays
               .stream( NickName.values() )
               .map( NickName :: getDisplayName )
               .toArray()
    }
```

## Print all enum objects’ name

You said:

> I want to print
>
> `JENNIFER MICHAEL WILLIAM`

Simply call [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) to combine each enum object name.

```
String output = String.join( " " , NickName.values() ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`name()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#name()) to print the constant name of the enum:

> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration.

For example:

```java
String concatenatedNickNames = Arrays.stream(NickNames.values())
    .map(NickNames::name)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(concatenatedNickNames );
```

Comment: Good simple solution.